# Como copiar commits de um branch para o outro?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Estou usando o seguinte workflow com git:

1. Defino uma tarefa
2. Crio um branch para ela a partir do master
3. Implemento a tarefa
4. Faço pull no master
5. Faço merge da minha branch no master
6. Faço push do master

Porém, Pulei a etapa numero (2) e comitei todo o meu código no master. Como posso fazer para trocar meus commits do master para uma outra branch?

Comment: Quer trocar os commits para o master e depois tirar os originais do master ou deixá-los lá ficar?

Comment: @luiscubal Quero tirar os commits do master, e colocar em uma nova branch.

Comment: Sei que a pergunta já encontra-se resolvida, mas para aumentar a linha de conhecimento dos conteúdos já postados. Neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170531/%C3%89-possivel-alterar-a-ordem-dos-commits-da-minha-branch/216268#216268) há um mini tutorial de como aplicar o comando *cherry-pick* onde o intuito é repassar *commits* de uma *branch* específica para outra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obtenha o SHA1 do primeiro commit que deve ser movido. Você pode fazer isso com:

```
git checkout master
git log
```

```
# Cria o branch apontando para o HEAD
git branch nomedobranch
# reseta o master descartando commits
git reset --hard <sha1 do commit>
```

Nesse caso o novo branch terá todos os *commits* e o master será resetado para não conter os *commits* do *branch* (você pode fazer um `merge` novamente se quiser).

---

**P.S.:** Estou assumindo que você ainda não executou o passo 6 (`push`), caso contrário você vai ter que fazer um `push -f` e alinhar com as pessoas que já executaram o commando `pull` e obtiveram esses *commits* do repositório remoto. Eles também devem descartar os *commits* localmente antes de fazer `push`, ou eles reintroduzirão os *commits* no `master`.

**P.S. 2:** Também estou assumindo que você tem uma sequência "limpa" de *commits* para mover para o novo *branch*. Isso é, o `HEAD` é o último *commit* que deve pertencer ao *branch* e não existem *commits* intermediários que não devem pertencer ao *branch* desde o *commit* inicial (e.g., não houve um `pull` no meio do caminho introduzindo *commits* não relacionados ao *brach*). Se isso não for verdade você deve fazer `cherry-pick` apenas dos *commits* que deseja.

```
 # Cria novo branch apontando para o primeiro commit
 git checkout -b nomedobranch <sha1 do primeiro commit> 
 git cherry-pick <sha1 do segundo commit>
 git cherry-pick <sha1 do terceiro commit>
 git cherry-pick <sha1 do quarto commit>
```

---

**Fonte:** [SOE - How can I move recent commit(s) to a new branch with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/how-can-i-move-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git).

Comment: Nota: o git branch não muda de branch (apenas o cria). Portanto, se já estiver no master, não é preciso executar `git checkout master`.

Comment: Estava editando :). Corrigido

Comment: Às vezes a forma mais "burra" é mais sábia, porque evita perder-se no processo. Pode ser mais simples gerar os patches com git format-patch, e depois aplicar manualmente com git am ou git am -3.

Comment: Olá epx, os patches são uma boa alternativa, porém não acho que reduzem o trabalho nesse caso. No caso de *commits* lineares ainda é necessário obter o hash do primeiro *commit*, gerar o conjunto de *patches* desse *commit* até o HEAD, criar o *branch*, aplicar os *patches* e resetar o master.

Answer (score 4):

**Atenção**: Você não deve realizar esse procedimento se já tiver forçado o `push` para o repositório remoto, pois outros desenvolvedores já podem ter realizado o `pull` desse repositório.

Você não precisa retirar os `commits` do master local para um outro `branch` se você não quiser realmente. O seu problema é que você fez o `pull` do master remoto, só que os `commits` que já estavam no master remoto ficaram acima das suas mudanças commitadas recentemente, para reordenar os `commits` no master local, você pode utilizar o código abaixo:

```sh
git rebase -i HEAD~<número_de_commits_que_devem_ser_reordenados>
```

- A flag `-i` é o modo iterativo
- O `HEAD` é o ultimo `commit` no `branch`
- O `~` é uma especie de subtração

Suponha que `<número_de_commits_que_devem_ser_reordenados>` seja 3, o significado de `HEAD~3` é de realizar a tarefa a partir do antepenúltimo `commit`.

Serão exibidos os `commits`, somo a seguir em um editor como o `vi`, note que todas as linhas antecedidas pelo caractere `#` são comentários explicativos sobre o que você pode realizar com o comando `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

```
pick 4c39bca gemspec tweak
pick 85409cf Version bump to 0.4.1
pick eb32194 Regenerated gemspec for version 0.4.1

# Rebase 60709da..eb32194 onto 60709da
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Suponha que as 3 primeiras linhas são os `commits` que você deve reordenar,
Suponha também que você deseja reordenar de forma que o terceiro `commit` fique
em primeiro

Logo reordene as 3 primeiras linhas para a seguinte ordem:

```
pick eb32194 Regenerated gemspec for version 0.4.1
pick 4c39bca gemspec tweak
pick 85409cf Version bump to 0.4.1

# Rebase 60709da..eb32194 onto 60709da
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Salve e saia do `vi` pronto seus commits estarão reordenados com as ultimas alterações na `HEAD` do `branch`

Se você realmente deseja que eles estejam em outro `branch` ai realize o `git cherry-pick <commit_hash>` a partir do branch cópia.

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar a etapa 2, primeiramente você deve estar na branch master
você pode fazer isso com `git checkout master`
Após isso deve-se então criar a branch da tarefa (etapa 2), fazendo uma cópia da master, levando em conta, que é isso que você queria originalmente, certo?.

```
git checkout -b novaBranch
```

Após esse comando sua branch nova (cópia da atual master) já estará selecionada, então retorne para branch master com `git checkout master`.

Agora você deve voltar para uma versão antes do commit da tarefa mencionada na master.
digite `git log` para listar seus commits, procure pelo Nº sha1 como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Digitando `git reset --hard 621256` (os 6 primeiros já são suficientes) retornarei ao tempo, neste exemplo voltei para o primeiro commit, e estará sendo apagado os commits posteriores. Mas lembre-se, você fez uma cópia da branch master para uma outra branch com a tarefa feita.

Apartir de agora você poderá seguir com seu procedimento correto.