# É possivel alterar a ordem dos commits da minha branch?

Tags: git

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu alterar as ordens dos commits da minha branch.

Motivo: Fiz commit gigantesco, com alterações de baixa e **grande** importância para o sistema(que podem matar o sistema), e agora quero ir fazendo as alterações em vários commits, para separar o que tem baixa importância, das que tem grande importância.

Answer (score 2):

Eu passei por um problema parecido e a solução que irei repassar agora me atendeu perfeitamente. Irei fazer como um passo-a-passo minucioso para também ajudar outras pessoas que pelo menos tenha o básico do git, que é criar, excluir, atualizar e alternar *branch's*, "*commitar*" e outros.

A princípio eu criei uma nova *branch* para não aplicar comandos que possam inviabilizar o uso da *branch* no futuro.

1. Em primeiro lugar atualize a master, logo após, atualize sua `*branch*-antiga` a partir da master e, também, a partir da master crie uma `*branch*-nova`. O objetivo será aplicar *commit* por *commit* da `*branch*-antiga` na `*branch*-nova`;
2. Na `*branch*-antiga`utilize o comando: `git log --author="Fulano da Silva" --name-only`. O que este comando faz? O [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) mostra os logs de confirmação e os parâmetros `--author=<pattern>` aplica um "*pattern*" no cabeçalho do *commit*. Neste caso irá buscar os *commit's* pelo nome e `--name-only` mostra os "caminho/nomes" dos arquivos alterados. Segue exemplo da saída do código completo no terminal:

   ```
   commit 94d580b6c9480ac23908799681bebc947a3e760f  
   Author: Djalma Manfrin <djalma.manfrin@email.com>
   Date:   Fri Jan 6 11:12:03 2017 -0200

   nome do commit

   caminho/do/arquivo/arquivo_1.php
   caminho/do/arquivo/arquivo_2.php
   caminho/do/arquivo/arquivo_3.php
   ```

Obs.: Perceba que os *commit* estão em ordem. Do mais recente para o mais antigo. Esta ordem é importante para o próximo passo. Iremos aplicar *commit* por *commit* do mais antigo para o mais novo.

3. Para facilitar, divida a tela do terminal em duas telas. Em uma tela execute o comando do passo 2 para listar os *commit's* e na outra, mude para a `*branch*-nova` e aplique o comando: `git cherry-pick 68e4bde4a83910cb0b4a8df82078e70131ce9280`. O que este comando faz? O [git-cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) aplica as alterações na *branch* atual de um *commit* existente. Altere a *hash* conforme explicado no passo 2, do mais antigo para o mais novo.

Obs.: Normalmente ao executar o comando `git cherry-pick` não gera conflito, mas caso gere, terá que resolver no braço analisando o código que queira "*commitar*". Cada conflito é um caso particular e se acontecer comente ou abra uma nova pergunta no *Stack* para que possamos te ajudar. Caso não seja necessário mexer no *commit*, pule para o passo 5

4. Como havia informado na pergunta e como também era meu caso. Em um único *commit* havia alterações de baixo e grande impacto ao sistema como um todo. Então, nesse caso tive que aplicar o comando: `git reset HEAD^1`. O que este comando faz? O [git-reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) reinicializa o *HEAD* atual para o estado especificado passados como parâmetros. No nosso caso o estado especificado será `HEAD^1`.

Obs.: No grosso modo, o comando `git-reset` é o oposto do `git add`. A nossa especificação `HEAD^1` significa que queremos alterar/voltar o *HEAD* um *commit* para trás. Este *commit* não é perdido. Ele volta como alterações que podem ser "commitadas". Isso irá permitir voltar as alterações um *commit* e "commitá-la em partes". No nosso caso, será possível separar por *commit* as complexibilidade em baixa e grande. Por fim, *commit* as alterações conforme necessite.

5. Após terminar o atual *commit*, volte para o passo 3. Esta foi a forma que encontrei para resolver meu problema. Espero que te ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o **git reset** para retornar para o momento antes de você realizar seus commits. O seu código não será perdido apenas voltará para **working directory** (aquele momento antes de dar add e commit), e então a partir daí você pode ir dando add e commit aos poucos conforme necessita.

Para isso obtenha o hash do commit anterior ao seu (pode utlizar git log para verificar isso) e passar como parâmetro para o git reset, exemplo:

```
git reset 2af93c4f8c7c2eb55900a11eg6cf8184be18e041
```

Desta forma irá constar que o último commit foi o do hash passado no reset e todas as suas alterações estarão disponíveis para dar add...